# What's the individual net worth by age in Canada?

Tags: canada, statistics, net-worth

I see that the government use the net worth of the median household, but they don't check the individual net worth instead. I was wondering if there was any source for this. The only thing I found is this web page, but it doesn't seem to be accurate, so I was wondering if there was a way to measure it or a place that showed this statistics, or a way to accurately infer the individual net worth for each working adult.

https://www.thekickassentrepreneur.com/net-worth-by-age-percentile-calculator-for-canada/

https://www.freedomthirtyfiveblog.com/resources/median-and-average-net-worth

Found this, but it doesn't include the statistics I want, but a useful statistics I found is the target for singles and couples.

Comment: How would you get "individual net worth" for two married people that have joint ownership of everything?

Comment: @sayaman I don't see the connection of this question to personal finance. Can you clarify how this relates?

Comment: you need to plan out your retirement by seeing how well you compare to the average person, and then checking what some people would recommend you having at X age. Because I am single, it's hard to interpret median household income and what it means for me.

Comment: Can't you "estimate" individual net worth by seeing how much each adult woudl get after a divorce?

Comment: "you need to plan out your retirement by seeing how well you compare to the average person, and then checking what some people would recommend you having at X age. " I understand what you mean about wanting a reference point for yourself, but be careful of using an average like this to plan for yourself - the rules of thumb will be too generic to be more than a starting point.

Comment: I understand that people who spend more need to save more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a "Persons not in an economic family"  Check statscan for tables.

Here's [Assets and Debts](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=1110001601&pickMembers%5B0%5D=1.1&pickMembers%5B1%5D=3.4&pickMembers%5B2%5D=5.5&pickMembers%5B3%5D=4.3&cubeTimeFrame.startYear=2005&cubeTimeFrame.endYear=2019&referencePeriods=20050101%2C20190101). You can also find a table for income etc.., you can change the province or age etc..  This all comes from a "Survey of Financial Security" that Canada does every so often.  You can read them all.

Answer (score -4):

There has been a significant increase in the average net worth of the citizens residing in Canada.

Speaking of the year 2023 Canadian household has a net worth of $329,900, while the country's average net worth is $738,200. This value is all time high compared to its 2016 value which was $312,500.

The country's average net worth has also seen a rise of 96% in last 7 years of its previous value which was $708900 in 2016.

Comment: what does any of this mean?